# When using an extbase query, can I order the results by a field in a linked model?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am querying a Model*, which has a field that refers to another Model. Is it possible to order the results using a field in the linked Model?

So for example:

Car contains a field which refers to its OWner. I want to show all Cars sorted by their owner.

(I don't want to use the statement() method since in that case I would have to write the whole query myself)

(*) using http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_generic_1_1_query.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (don't care for the `$constraint` for the moment):

```
$query->matching($constraint)->setOrderings(
    array('owner.sorting' => Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING)
)->execute();
```

Assuming the field in you `Car` model is named `owner` and you want to sort by `sorting` field of the `Owner` model/table.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad this leaves out all results for which there is no owner :) (although I think I understand why this is in MySql)

Comment: By the way, too bad this quite powerful feature isn't documented! Or is it?

Comment: Actually I don't know, I just try things out in TYPO3 context as some of fun stuff never gets documented properly (in my experience) or if, it's hard to find :-) In the years of working with TYPO3, I had quite some of those moments when I thought "cool, that works" when I originally expected something to crash. (especially with typoscript)

Comment: @Michael, welcome to the club: wow! it works but... why the @&#%* ;)

Answer (score 1):

When working with 6.2

->setOrderings(Array('model.yourfield' =>  \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING))

Answer (score 0):

@Michael and @rob-ot are right. There is one pitfall that took me many hours and that I'd like to mention here:

If your sort field in your related table contains **underscores**, you have to provide its name to setSortOrderings in lowerCamelCase:

```
// with database column name my_car_sorting you must define:
$query->matching($constraint)->setOrderings(
    array('owner.myCarSorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING)
)->execute();
```