# setOrderings in extbase (TYPO3) for second level of an Array

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

i want to Sort my "Appointments" by date via this function in the EventRepository of my TYPO3 Extension.

```
    public function findAll() {

    // Sort appointments ascending
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    Return $query->setOrderings (
        Array('appointments' => Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Query::ORDER_ASCENDING)
    )->execute();

}
```

I need to get the second Level of the Array, like: 'appointments.start_date'
My Array looks like this:

```
images => 'originalPreviewJW__2_.jpg' (25 chars)
     categories => Tx_Extbase_Persistence_ObjectStorageprototype object (2 items)
     appointments => Tx_Extbase_Persistence_ObjectStorageprototype object (4 items)
        000000006052eef7000000009b41588e => Tx_SzEvents_Domain_Model_Appointmentprototypepersistent entity (uid=3, pid=13)
              titel => 'entertainment area' (18 chars)
              startDate => DateTimeprototype object (2013-08-22T10:00:00+02:00, 1377158400)
              endDate => DateTimeprototype object (2013-08-22T20:00:00+02:00, 1377194400)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using an extbase query, can I order the results by a field in a linked model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993137/when-using-an-extbase-query-can-i-order-the-results-by-a-field-in-a-linked-mode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
public function findAll() {
    // Sort appointments ascending
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    return $query->setOrderings (
        Array('appointments.startDate' => Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Query::ORDER_ASCENDING)
    )->execute();
}
```

Comment: Great! It is very important to see that the referenced column is addressed as ``appointments.startDate`` although the table field name is actually ``start_date``! Also important: The way to address the sorting direction constant has been changed in ExtBase from ``Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Query::ORDER_ASCENDING`` to ``\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING``